# Реально ли смержить ветки с разницей больше 700 коммитов?

Tags: git-merge, branch

Недавно переключили на проект в котором по моему мнению большой бардак с ветками. В самом репозитории висит больше 100 веток, и похоже что их никто не когда не чистил. Для добавленя новых фич используется ветка дев, но при этом есть еще ветка с новым дизайном и разница с девом там еще на прошлой неделе была больше 700 коммитов. 
Предложил менеджменту их начать их мержить сейчас потому что мне страшно подумать как на финале эта вся каша будет мержится. сначала вроде согласились, но потом ультимативно отказались без каких-либо аргументов. при этом до внутреннего дедлайна для релиза осталось около двух недель
Есть ощущения что на дедлайне будет куча матов и криков от менеджмента почему разрабы такие тупые и не могут собрать все в одно целое
есть ли какие-то нормальные решения для такой ситуации и насколько типично - делать слияния веток где есть такое большое число отличий?

Comment: Очевидно, всё зависит не от числа коммитов, а от содержимого веток и характера отличий. А менеджмент вроде бы вообще не должен решать, что, как и куда сливать, для этого есть разработчики и возможно тимлид

Comment: Ну и по идее ничего не должно мешать вмержить дев в дизайн, а не дизайн в дев